# How can I callback as a CABasicAnimation is animating?

Tags: iphone, caanimation, uianimation

I have an animation I'm using to snap a rotatable UIView to a circular grid. As the view animates, I need to update another view based on the rotating views position.

How can I go about getting the position of the rotating view **as** it animates into position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When animation starts you can start a function that will be polling current view position using a timer (I suppose you will need to get `presentationLayer` from view's layer and get position values from it).

There's no callbacks for CAAnimation other than `animationDidStart` and `animationDidStop` so it seems that's the solution (if I'm not mistaken it was also mentioned so in one of WWDC videos).